# Defining a field homomorphism on a generating set

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

My question arises from the following problem. Consider the field $K=\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]{2},\sqrt[3]{3},\sqrt[3]{5}),$ and define a map $f$  via
$$f(\sqrt[3]{2})=\sqrt[3]{2} e^{2i\pi/3}, f(\sqrt[3]{3})=\sqrt[3]{3}, f(\sqrt[3]{5})=\sqrt[3]{5}.$$ I want to show that this extends (uniquely) into a field morphism $f' : K \to \overline{\Bbb Q}$.
The issue is that the different cubic roots must be proved to be linearly independent, and even more, we want for instance $\sqrt[3]{3} \not\in \Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]{2})$ (because otherwise the value of $f'$ on $\sqrt[3]{3}$ will be determined by its value on $\sqrt[3]{2}$).

$$ $$

So more generally, assume that $K / \Bbb Q$ is a finite extension and $E \subset K$ is a finite set with $K = \Bbb Q(E)$. I want to know nice sufficient conditions such that:

- $(*)$ any map $f : E \to \Bbb C$ such that $f(a)$ has the same minimal polynomial as $a$, for any $a \in E$, extends into a field morphism $f' : K \to \Bbb C$.

My guess is that the condition

- $a \not \in \Bbb Q(E \setminus \{a\})$ for any $a \in E$

is sufficient. **Question 1 : is it correct? If not, what are sufficient conditions?**

(The aside question $2$ is to determine whether the set $\{\sqrt[3]{2},\sqrt[3]{3},\sqrt[3]{5}\}$ satisfies my condition just above).

Comment: You may find the theorem I reference in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2080741/how-can-we-check-that-there-exist-such-elements/2080850#2080850) helpful.

Comment: @Quasicoherent  :  thank you, but this is only for $|E| = 1$, which I already know (and this is a very easy case). But maybe one can proceed by induction on $|E|$ to answer my question 1.

Comment: Yes, you can apply the result successively to $\mathbb{Q} \subseteq \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}) \subseteq \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}, \sqrt[3]{3})$. If you look at the linked answer, you'll see that I applied the theorem in an example where $2$ elements were adjoined. The tricky part is making sure that the minimal polynomial of one element remains irreducible over the extension obtained by adjoining the other element.

Comment: Let me call $(*)$ the "Galois independence" property for $E$. Then : algebraically independent $\implies$ Galois independent $\implies$ linearly independent. Typically, $\{e, \pi\}$ is algebraically independent and one has the desired extension property in order to get field morphisms. Also, $\{\sqrt 2 , \sqrt 3, \sqrt 6\}$ is linearly independent but not Galois independent.

Comment: @Quasicoherent : yes, the main problem is to know whether the min. polynomial remains irreducible. That's why I considered the condition $(*)$ above. My question is to know whether it is a sufficient condition (typically, if it ensures that the min. poly. remains irreducible, then we're done).

Comment: In the category of groups, if $G$ has presentation $G = <S \mid R>$, one can define a map on the generators $S$ and then use the universal property of quotient. In the category of $k$-vector spaces, one can just find a generating set which is _linearly independent_ in order to define a morphism. But my question is about the category of _fields_ (or $\Bbb Q$-algebras).

Comment: To solve this kind of question (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1785159), we may define $f(\sqrt 3) = -\sqrt 3$, which has an extension to $\bar{\Bbb Q}$. But 1) here my question includes cases where we want to define $f$ on a finite set $E$ of cardinality $>1$ and 2) It's not clear that $f(\sqrt 3 + \sqrt[3]{2}) \neq \sqrt 3 + \sqrt[3]{2}$ (which would show that $\sqrt 3 + \sqrt[3]{2}$ is irrational, by Galois theory), because we don't know what $f(\sqrt[3]{2})$ is [precisely my question is to know that setting $f(\sqrt[3]{2}) = \sqrt[3]{2} \zeta_3$ is fine, which needs ….

Comment: … some algebraic independence with $\sqrt 3$.]  $$ $$ (Actually, to solve the cited question in particular, it's better to first define $f(\sqrt[3]{2}) := \sqrt[3]{2} \zeta_3$, and then to extend it by Axiom of choice to $\bar{\Bbb Q}$. Then $f(\sqrt 3) = \pm \sqrt 3$ is real for sure, so $f$ cannot fix $\sqrt 3 + \sqrt[3]{2}$, hence it is an irrational number !)

Comment: The above example is a bit trivial, since $\sqrt 3 + \sqrt[3]{2}$ rational would imply $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]{2}) \subset \Bbb Q(\sqrt 2)$, impossible for degree reasons. So instead, how would you apply my question to prove Galois-non-invariance of $\sqrt[3]{2}+\sqrt[3]{3}+\sqrt[3]{5}$, for instance (it was deleted from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2041887)…)?

Answer (score 1):

This condition does not imply your desired property in general. For example, suppose that $f \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ is an irreducible quartic polynomial with Galois group $D_4$. Then the splitting field $K$ of $f$ is generated by two roots of $f$, say $K = \mathbb{Q}(\alpha_1,\alpha_2)$. The element $\alpha_2$ has degree two over $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha_1)$, and vice versa, so your criterion is satisfied. Let's denote the other roots by $\{\alpha_3, \alpha_4\}$. Then not every injective mapping of $\{\alpha_1,\alpha_2\} \to \{\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3,\alpha_4\}$ extends to an automorphism $K \to K$, since there are $12$ such maps, but only $8$ automorphisms of $K$.

An example of such an $f$ is $x^4 - 2x^2 - 2$.